# How to check for file updates after 5 min intervals with autoit?

Tags: autoit

I'm trying to get some sort of script working so It checks two files every 5 mins to check if they've updated/changed/been modified.

If file 1 has been updated/changed/been modified it should do one thing, if file 2 has been updated/changed/been modified it should close a certain program and launch a new program then change the programs title and move it to 0, 0 (top left of screen)

The part I don't know how to do is the checking the files to see if they've been updated/changed/been modified.

Could someone help me and point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for `FileGetTime`, specifically with the option set to 0 (modified)

#### Code Example

```
Func Timecheck()
    $file1_2 = FileGetTime("C:\file1.txt", 0, 1)
    $file2_2 = FileGetTime("C:\file2.txt", 0, 1)
    If $file1_1 == $file1_2 Then
        ; Do something here if file 1 isn't modified within 5ins
    EndIf
    If $file2_1 == $file2_2 Then
        ; Maybe WinClose?
        WinClose("programhere")
        ; Maybe ProcessClose
        ProcessClose("process.exe")
        ; Launch your program...
        Run(...)
        ; Wait for process
        ProcessWait("process.exe")
        ; Wait for Program...
        WinWait("programhere")
        WinSetTitle("programhere", "", "newprogramhere")
        WinMove("newprogramheret", "", 0, 0, 800, 600, 1)
    EndIf
    $file1_1 = FileGetTime("C:\file1.txt", 0, 1)
    $file2_1 = FileGetTime("C:\file2.txt", 0, 1)
EndFunc

; Initial Launch, grab current GetTime
$file1_1 = FileGetTime("C:\file1.txt", 0, 1)
$file2_1 = FileGetTime("C:\file2.txt", 0, 1)

While 1
    Sleep(300000)
    Timecheck()
WEnd
```

Reference: http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/FileGetTime.htm